# Save radiobuttons after being clear

Tags: radio-button, radio-group

I've created a small quiz of 3 questions, every one of them has 4 answers in a radio button to choose, and at the end of the quiz the application will show a message depending upon the answers chosen, the questions are all on 1 layout with a group of radio buttons, that is cleared every time we go on next question.

My problem is that I don't know how to make the app remember the choices, is there a way to save the answers and then clear the group and save the next choice...etc. like in a string something like "1-3-2-1"

Answer (score 0):

There are a few typical approaches to this.

You could store the results of each question in the session server side. Each time the user submits the form, the result gets posted to the server. The server can then remember the result, and at the end of the quiz the server can use this to generate the results page.

You could use a RESTful URI scheme. The results page could then have a url like:

```
http://myapp/results?question1=answer1&question2=answer2&question3=answer3
```

I am not clear from your question on how the questions are generated. If they come through AJAX, then you could store the results in javascript each time a POST is made. If the questions require separate page loads, then you will need to use one of the above approaches.